# Wordpress 3.8 jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a blog using Wordpress version 3.8 (http://tech-article.com). If I visit my site as a user it is working well. But if I visit my site after logging in as an admin than then hot post area JQuery effects such as rendering the post title and post avatar are not working.

I opened the console and got what you see below. May be JQuery is not working?

```
"undefined"!=typeof jQuery?("undefined"==typeof jQuery.fn.hoverIntent&&!function(a){a.fn.hoverIntent=function(b,c,d){var e={interval:100,sensitivity:7,timeout:0};e="object"==typeof b?a.extend(e,b):a.isFunction(c)?a.extend(e,{over:b,out:c,selector:d}):a.extend(e,{over:b,out:b,selector:c});var f,g,h,i,j=function(a){f=a.pageX,g=a.pageY},k=function(b,c){return c.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(c.hoverIntent_t),Math.abs(h-f)+Math.abs(i-g)<e.sensitivity?(a(c).off("mousemove.hoverIntent",j),c.hoverIntent_s=1,e.over.apply(c,[b])):(h=f,i=g,c.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){k(b,c)},e.interval),void 0)},l=function(a,b){return b.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(b.hoverIntent_t),b.hoverIntent_s=0,e.out.apply(b,[a])},m=function(b){var c=jQuery.extend({},b),d=this;d.hoverIntent_t&&(d.hoverIntent_t=clearTimeout(d.hoverIntent_t)),"mouseenter"==b.type?(h=c.pageX,i=c.pageY,a(d).on("mousemove.hoverIntent",j),1!=d.hoverIntent_s&&(d.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){k(c,d)},e.interval))):(a(d).off("mousemove.hoverIntent",j),1==d.hoverIntent_s&&(d.hoverIntent_t=setTimeout(function(){l(c,d)},e.timeout)))};return this.on({"mouseenter.hoverIntent":m,"mouseleave.hoverIntent":m},e.selector)}}(jQuery),jQuery(document).ready(function(a){var b,c,d,e=a("#wpadminbar"),f=!1;b=function(b,c){var d=a(c),e=d.attr("tabindex");e&&d.attr("tabindex","0").attr("tabindex",e)},c=function(b){e.find("li.menupop").on("click.wp-mobile-hover",function(c){var d=a(this);d.parent().is("#wp-admin-bar-root-default")&&!d.hasClass("hover")?(c.preventDefault(),e.find("li.menupop.hover").removeClass("hover"),d.addClass("hover")):d.hasClass("hover")||(c.stopPropagation(),c.preventDefault(),d.addClass("hover")),b&&(a("li.menupop").off("click.wp-mobile-hover"),f=!1)})},d=function(){var b=/Mobile\/.+Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)?"touchstart":"click";a(document.body).on(b+".wp-mobile-hover",function(b){a(b.target).closest("#wpadminbar").length||e.find("li.menupop.hover").removeClass("hover")})},e.removeClass("nojq").removeClass("nojs"),"ontouchstart"in window?(e.on("touchstart",function(){c(!0),f=!0}),d()):/IEMobile\/[1-9]/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(c(),d()),e.find("li.menupop").hoverIntent({over:function(){f||a(this).addClass("hover")},out:function(){f||a(this).removeClass("hover")},timeout:180,sensitivity:7,interval:100}),window.location.hash&&window.scrollBy(0,-32),a("#wp-admin-bar-get-shortlink").click(function(b){b.preventDefault(),a(this).addClass("selected").children(".shortlink-input").blur(function(){a(this).parents("#wp-admin-bar-get-shortlink").removeClass("selected")}).focus().select()}),a("#wpadminbar li.menupop > .ab-item").bind("keydown.adminbar",function(c){if(13==c.which){var d=a(c.target),e=d.closest("ab-sub-wrapper");c.stopPropagation(),c.preventDefault(),e.length||(e=a("#wpadminbar .quicklinks")),e.find(".menupop").removeClass("hover"),d.parent().toggleClass("hover"),d.siblings(".ab-sub-wrapper").find(".ab-item").each(b)}}).each(b),a("#wpadminbar .ab-item").bind("keydown.adminbar",function(c){if(27==c.which){var d=a(c.target);c.stopPropagation(),c.preventDefault(),d.closest(".hover").removeClass("hover").children(".ab-item").focus(),d.siblings(".ab-sub-wrapper").find(".ab-item").each(b)}}),a("#wpadminbar").click(function(b){("wpadminbar"==b.target.id||"wp-admin-bar-top-secondary"==b.target.id)&&(b.preventDefault(),a("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"fast"))}),a(".screen-reader-shortcut").keydown(function(b){var c,d;13==b.which&&(c=a(this).attr("href"),d=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),-1!=d.indexOf("applewebkit")&&c&&"#"==c.charAt(0)&&setTimeout(function(){a(c).focus()},100))}),"sessionStorage"in window&&a("#wp-admin-bar-logout a").click(function(){try{for(var a in sessionStorage)-1!=a.indexOf("wp-autosave-")&&sessionStorage.removeItem(a)}catch(b){}}),navigator.userAgent&&-1===document.body.className.indexOf("no-font-face")&&/Android (1.0|1.1|1.5|1.6|2.0|2.1)|Nokia|Opera Mini|w(eb)?OSBrowser|webOS|UCWEB|Windows Phone OS 7|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|MSIE 7/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(document.body.className+=" no-font-face")})):!function(a,b){var c,d=function(a,b,c){a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener(b,c,!1):a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+b,function(){return c.call(a,window.event)})},e=new RegExp("\\bhover\\b","g"),f=[],g=new RegExp("\\bselected\\b","g"),h=function(a){for(var b=f.length;b--;)if(f[b]&&a==f[b][1])return f[b][0];return!1},i=function(b){for(var d,i,j,k,l,m,n=[],o=0;b&&b!=c&&b!=a;)"LI"==b.nodeName.toUpperCase()&&(n[n.length]=b,i=h(b),i&&clearTimeout(i),b.className=b.className?b.className.replace(e,"")+" hover":"hover",k=b),b=b.parentNode;if(k&&k.parentNode&&(l=k.parentNode,l&&"UL"==l.nodeName.toUpperCase()))for(d=l.childNodes.length;d--;)m=l.childNodes[d],m!=k&&(m.className=m.className?m.className.replace(g,""):"");for(d=f.length;d--;){for(j=!1,o=n.length;o--;)n[o]==f[d][1]&&(j=!0);j||(f[d][1].className=f[d][1].className?f[d][1].className.replace(e,""):"")}},j=function(b){for(;b&&b!=c&&b!=a;)"LI"==b.nodeName.toUpperCase()&&!function(a){var b=setTimeout(function(){a.className=a.className?a.className.replace(e,""):""},500);f[f.length]=[b,a]}(b),b=b.parentNode},k=function(b){for(var d,e,f,h=b.target||b.srcElement;;){if(!h||h==a||h==c)return;if(h.id&&"wp-admin-bar-get-shortlink"==h.id)break;h=h.parentNode}for(b.preventDefault&&b.preventDefault(),b.returnValue=!1,-1==h.className.indexOf("selected")&&(h.className+=" selected"),d=0,e=h.childNodes.length;e>d;d++)if(f=h.childNodes[d],f.className&&-1!=f.className.indexOf("shortlink-input")){f.focus(),f.select(),f.onblur=function(){h.className=h.className?h.className.replace(g,""):""};break}return!1},l=function(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g;if(!("wpadminbar"!=a.id&&"wp-admin-bar-top-secondary"!=a.id||(b=window.pageYOffset||document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop||0,1>b)))for(g=b>800?130:100,c=Math.min(12,Math.round(b/g)),d=b>800?Math.round(b/30):Math.round(b/20),e=[],f=0;b;)b-=d,0>b&&(b=0),e.push(b),setTimeout(function(){window.scrollTo(0,e.shift())},f*c),f++};d(b,"load",function(){c=a.getElementById("wpadminbar"),a.body&&c&&(a.body.appendChild(c),c.className&&(c.className=c.className.replace(/nojs/,"")),d(c,"mouseover",function(a){i(a.target||a.srcElement)}),d(c,"mouseout",function(a){j(a.target||a.srcElement)}),d(c,"click",k),d(c,"click",function(a){l(a.target||a.srcElement)}),d(document.getElementById("wp-admin-bar-logout"),"click",function(){if("sessionStorage"in window)try{for(var a in sessionStorage)-1!=a.indexOf("wp-autosave-")&&sessionStorage.removeItem(a)}catch(b){}})),b.location.hash&&b.scrollBy(0,-32),navigator.userAgent&&-1===document.body.className.indexOf("no-font-face")&&/Android (1.0|1.1|1.5|1.6|2.0|2.1)|Nokia|Opera Mini|w(eb)?OSBrowser|webOS|UCWEB|Windows Phone OS 7|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|MSIE 7/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&(document.body.className+=" no-font-face")})}(document,window);
```

When I used it with wordpress 3.6 it worked well. But this the problem appeared after update to version 3.8. Please give proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just took a casual look at your blog, it has jquery 1.4.2 included in your theme this is probably getting overwritten by "admin bar" javascript/jquery when you are logged in as admin. I am not sure as I never check if adminbar include it's own jquery. But remove jquery from theme and use wordpress enqueue function to include wordpress' default jquery this always ensure that you have one and latest version of jquery always included.

Comment: Thanks, I am using wordpress default jquery. If you like I can give you my theme. Please give me your email id, I will mail you theme.

Comment: It maybe that the extension isn't using the default query. Have a look in your source on the pade having problems and find a jquery function - does it have something like $j - if it does it is in no conflict mode (very likely) and you will need to use it like that :)

Comment: what kind of problem is this. Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Answer (score 0):

Really we need some more information code, server etc to provide the best help but I would suggest that it is likely once you login a new extension is becoming active. It may be loading Jquery and thus causing some sort of conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I am using wordpress default jquery. If you like I can give you my theme. Please give me your email id, I will mail you theme.